# BroadcastReceiver isn't receiving ACTION_SCREEN_OFF intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have created a `BroadcastReceiver` that should listen for the "ACTION_SCREEN_OFF" intent.

```
public class ExampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // run a service..
    }

}
```

I have registered it in the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".path.to.ExampleReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But when the screen is turned off, the `onReceive()` method is not called. What else do I need to do to get this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` is not sent to receivers registered in the manifest. It is only sent to receivers registered via `registerReceiver()` from a running component.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where I might be able to find out what actions can be sent to receivers that are registered in the Manifest?

Comment: @crm: Most can. The roster of what can and cannot is not documented. `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`, `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`, and `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` are the big three that I can think of off the top of my head that only get sent to receivers registered through `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: @crmepham the explanation is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions